# Laravel Form submission Routing Error - The POST method is not supported for this route

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm building the settings page of my web application. This page includes several forms that submit to different routes on in my backend. The first time I submit the form everything works but when I try it the second time there is an error from Laravel.

**The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.**

I want to emphasis that it works the first time I submit the form this error comes up the second time I submit the form even after page refresh and page resubmission and restarting my laptop.
This is my form from the view

```
            <form action="{{ route('admin_add_user_role') }}" method="POST">
             {{ csrf_field() }}
            <td><input name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required/></td>
           <td><input name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description"/></td>
           <td><input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-info" value="save"/></td>
           </form>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my route for that form

```
Route::post('/admin/user_roles/add', 'AdminController@add_user_role')->name("admin_add_user_role");
```

[image: This is a screenshot of the error I get.]

Comment: Look at the error message, and look at your route. It's trying to POST to `/public/admin/configurations`, not `/admin/user_roles/add`. Are you sure that it's coming from this form?

Comment: _/public/admin/configurations_ is where the form being submitted is located.

Comment: Can you please change `Route::post('/admin/user_roles/add', 'AdminController@add_user_role')->name("admin_add_user_role");` to `Route::post('/public/admin/user_roles/add', 'AdminController@add_user_role')->name("admin_add_user_role");`?

Comment: Please share the route defintion in question. The given error screen shows a different URL than the one in the shared route definition

Comment: @NicoHaase
`<form action="{{ route('admin_add_user_role') }}" method="POST">` This outputs 
`<form action="http://crm.local/public/admin/user_roles/add" method="POST">`

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev
It didn't work

Comment: Please add all clarification to the question by editing it. If you submit a form that points to `/public/admin/user_roles/add`, why does your screenshot show another URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by naming each form on the page.
So `<form action="{{ route('admin_add_user_role') }}" name="form1" method="POST">`

and then `<form action="{{ route('admin_add_product_role') }}" name="form2"  method="POST">` in that order.